# Flatten nested arrays using mongodb aggregation in spring

Tags: java, mongodb, kotlin, spring-data, aggregation-framework

I am trying to flatten nested arrays using aggregation framework but I can not get the result I which.
my collection is :

```
[
    {
        "id" : "xxx",
        "countryName" : "xxx",
        "cities" : [
            {
                "id" : "xxx",
                "cityName" : "xxx"
            },
            {
                "id" : "xxx",
                "cityName" : "xxx"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to get the cities from all countries, the result I am looking for is :

```
[
    {
        "id" : "xxx",
        "cityName" : "xxx"
    },
    {
        "id" : "xxx",
        "cityName" : "xxx"
    }
]
```

I tried this request :

```
val aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
                Aggregation.group("cities")
        )

return mongoDb.aggregate(aggregation, Country::class.java, Any::class.java).mappedResults
```

But, I got this result :

```
[
    {
        "_id": [
            {
                "id": "xxx",
                "cityName": "xxx"
            },
            {
                "id": "xxx",
                "cityName": "xxx"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This aggregation will help you achieve your result, except that you have to adapt it with `Java` driver:

```js
db.countries.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$cities"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "cities": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$cities"
    }
  }
])
```